# Efficiently create Numpy arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 1000 pickle files that each one contains a dictionary with 3 NumPy arrays. For each file, the NumPy arrays have a size of  Nx100x100x3, Mx50x50x3, and Kx28x28x3 (three RGB image arrays with N, M, and K correspond to the number of frames). For each video this N, K, and M sizes are different. What I want to do is to concatenate all the corresponding NumPy arrays together (the arrays that contain the same size images). In order to do so I am doing the following process:

```
arr1 = []
arr2 = []
arr3 = []

dirs = locate_all_pickle_files(my_path)
for dir in dirs:

   dct = load(my_path + dir)

   img1 = dct["img1"]
   img2 = dct["img2"]
   img3 = dct["img3"]

   for item in img1:
      arr1.append(item)
   for item in img2:
      arr2.append(item)
   for item in img3:
      arr3.append(item)

arr1 = np.asarray(arr1)
arr2 = np.asarray(arr2)
arr3 = np.asarray(arr3)
```

The above code works properly, therefore, I am able to concatenate all the items for each pickle file for each corresponding image together. However, I am sure that this is not the most efficient way. Is there a more compact way to perform the same approach without maybe double for.

Comment: Why not save a list of numpy arrays? Then concatenate them all together using `np.concatenate(my_list_of_numpy_arrays)`. Way faster than moving items from numpy arrays to python objects and then back to numpy arrays.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq could you please explain more? My pickle files are already stored I cannot process them again if this is what you mean.

Comment: Is `img1` a numpy array?

Comment: Yes all of them are NumPy arrays (img1, img2 and img3).

Comment: Then instead of the inner for loops, do `arr1.append(img1)`. Then change `np.asarray` line to `arr1 = np.concatenate(arr1)`

Comment: But img1 for each pickle file has a different size in the number of frames. Is the concatenate command do its magic even with different sizes of arrays?

Comment: Read `concatenate` docs.  Experiment